# Android Studio: run on device different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, sign

I recently upgraded my pc with new components and resetted my OS and installed everything again. When I now want to continue working on an Android project and run it on my physical device as I have been doing for a long time, I get this error

[image: Error]

I'm still using the same keystore with the same keystore password, alias and key password. What could be the cause of a different signature? I've also noted that I can't generate a signed bundle. Could this be a bug in Android Studio 3.5? I didn't see it in the known issues page

EDIT: deleting/uninstalling the app is not an option. I want to update the old app with the new app and all data needs to be kept. I'm looking for the reason that the signature is different

Comment: might it be that you are trying to install a release build on top of a debug build? If they have the same package name in your setup, that can be the issue. Or the other way around, of course

Comment: try File > invalidate cache/restart

Comment: if you are using Room, upgrade your app then

Comment: Same problem, did you find a solution?